# Is the map $G*H \to G \times H$ injective?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, free-product

I am reading Hatcher's book on Algebraic topology. Here is a paragraph about free product of group.
[image]

I think the last line should not be "a surjective homomorphism", but an injective one, since the free product group is smaller than direct porduct group. Am I correct?

**Also, is the homomorphism $G*H \to G \times H$ simply inclusion homomorphism?** I treat $G*H$ as a subgroup of $G \times H$

Answer (score 3):

No it is not, you have a surjection from $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} $ whose kernel is the normal subgroup generated by $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}, x,y \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 2):

No. As you say, the free product of two groups **is not "smaller"** than the direct product, an easy counter example is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \ast \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is an infinite group, where $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ has only 4 elements.